# Why does this function filter out 'null' values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement, prototypejs

I am trying to write a quick function that filters out any falsy values. this seems to grab everything except 'null'.

please help!

```
function noFalsy(arr) {

var none=function(val){
         switch (val){
           case false:
           case null:
           case "":
           case 0:
           case undefined:
           case NaN:
             return false;
           default:
             return true;
         }
       },
  ans=[];
ans=arr.filter(none);


return ans;
}
```

Comment: It can't work for NaN because switch use a strict comparison and NaN !== NaN

Comment: If you just look for falsyness, you can do `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: The code you posted *does* filter out `null` for me? Did you pass in `"null"`?

Comment: @Bergi Should this be closed as non reproductible (or too messy) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check for `NaN` like that.

In JavaScript, `NaN !== NaN` is `true`. This is why you should use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) to check if a value is `NaN`; that's also the reason why your filter doesn't work for `NaN` values. The switch statement will never reach the `NaN` case's body, since the internal equality check will always fail.

If you just want to filter out falsy values, you could just rely on their falsiness instead of checking their exact value, which is a lot quicker:

```
[1, null, undefined, NaN, 0, "", true].filter(x => x); // [1, true]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your current code *does* filter out `null` values (however it won't filter out `NaN`). [See what I'm talking about](https://jsfiddle.net/de40443p/).

In your example, it's important to note that `NaN !== NaN` because there's now way to tell if "not a number" is the same as another element that is "not a number".

An easier way to omit any falsy values from an array is to iterate through the array, and return any values that are truthy:

```
function noFalsy(arr){
    var output = [];
    arr.filter(function(element){
        // If the element is not falsy, add it to our output array
        if(element){
            output.push(element);
        }
    });
    return output;
}

console.log(noFalsy([1, true, 0, null, false, NaN])); // => [1, true]
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Laxthkp2/)